# getSignedUrl when using cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get image url so that I can pass it as `src` in my html. I created functions and would like to send the url in response. I tried the below but I keep getting

> Error: Cannot sign data without `client_email`.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const getPicURL = functions.https.onRequest(
    (request, response) => {
        const storageBucket = admin
            .storage()
            .bucket('gs://my-app.appspot.com');

        const fileName = 'my-app/pic1.jpg';
        const tomorrow = new Date(
            new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        );

        const signedURL = storageBucket
            .file(fileName)
            .getSignedUrl({ action: 'read', expires: tomorrow });

        signedURL
            .then((data) => {
                response.send(data[0]);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('My Error', err);
                response.sendStatus(500).send(err);
            });
    }
);
```

I feel like I am missing configuration step but I don't know where to add these properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue I had is with service account. I was not initializing the app with  proper config. I could find the details in https://console.firebase.google.com/ >> Project >> Settings >> Service Account >> Firebase Admin SDK

[image: firebase console]

[image: firebase admin sdk]

Instead of just `admin.initializeApp();` we need to do the following

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When running this method locally using firebase functions:shell, initializing the storage object with project id and the path to key.json solved this issue for me. We have to initialize the storage like this

```
var storage = new Storage({
  projectId: "project id",
  keyFilename:"service-account-key.json"
});
```

Then you can generate the signed in url with the below sample

```
export const getPicUrl = functions.https.onCall(async (request) => {
  try {
    const options : GetSignedUrlConfig = {
      version: 'v4', // Use version 4 signing process
      action: "write", // Specify the action (read, write, delete, etc.)
      expires: Date.now() + expirationSeconds * 1000, // Expiration time in milliseconds
    };

    // Generate the signed URL
    const [signedUrl] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).getSignedUrl(options);

    console.log('Signed URL:', signedUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
});
```